# Get environment variables of a different service

Tags: c#, service, process, environment-variables, azure-service-fabric

I'm using Service Fabric. From one dedicated service, I would like to retrieve environment variables of others services. Is there a way to do that ? (Scan running services / loop / get environment variables / check if specified variable is set).

I already found a way with reading the process environment block ([here](https://blog.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/reading-environment-variables)) but if there are Service Fabric functions it could be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the environment variables from the service manifest but these can be overridden in the application manifest.
This doesn't take into account Environment variables the service creates at runtime.

```
var client = new FabricClient();
var serviceManifest = await client.ServiceManager.GetServiceManifestAsync("Application1Type", "1.0.0",
    "Service1Pkg");

var environmentVariables = XDocument.Parse(serviceManifest)
    .Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name == XName.Get("EnvironmentVariable", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"))
    .Select( x => new
    {
        Name = x.FirstAttribute.Value,
        Value = x.LastAttribute.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```